# React-Google-Charts Sankey bugging in responsive use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, primereact, react-google-charts

I'm working on a PrimeReact project. I used Sankey from Google-Charts (https://www.react-google-charts.com/examples/sankey). It works normally when not using any dynamic screen. However, as soon as I expand or collapse the sidebar, it stays like no changes happend (goes off the screen and don't fit in it or stays small and leaves space inside the card.) https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNb3S.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrGgG.png

It also corrects itself as soon as i adjust the browser's tab. I couldn't find any errors in the coding. It doesn't give any error at all. And works perfectly fine apart from the bug mentioned above. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<div className="card p-fluid min-w-full">
                <h5>Araç Türleri Şeması</h5>
                <GoogleCharts
                    chartType="Sankey"
                    data={data}
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    options={optionsSankey}
                />
            </div>
```

Comment: Not really PrimeReact related as all I see are CSS styles and Google Charts?

Comment: So, whats the way to solve this issue? I really couldn't find a way. I'll be appreciated if you help me. Thanks in advance.